# How to declare variable of the type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable?

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix

How to only declare the variable of the type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable?

If I try:

```
var selectedData="";
type selectedData=null;
```

I get errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<dynamic>` since the results from a `db.Query` are rows of dynamic.  C# compiler doesn't know the type at compile time of what a query will return.

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable selectedData;
```

and you can use it later in your code.

Comment: when i try it i face this error

CS0305: Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: If you want to use generic type then you should specify it like: System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<your type>

Comment: Please try to explain which type should be there? i want to pass 
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable selectedData=db.Query(SelectCategoryQuery,category);
value to it. what should i do?